# A native XML database management system needed

Tags: database, xml

Wanted: a native XML DBMS (for a single user, single-transaction environment).

Requirements:

- Unlimited number of attributes, elements, and namespaces
- Efficient search (SQL-like and XQuery), full-text indexing for several million documents per base

Desirable:

- low price or gratis
- possible horizontal scalability (into clusters)
- GUI for administration and search
- bindings for major languages (C++, Python, C)

OS: Windows, Linux.

[BaseX](http://basex.org) doesn't cut it because of restrictions on number of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Postgres

[Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/), the enterprise-quality relational database, handles [XML as a data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html). You can perform [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=XPath) queries inside the database engine. The text-search functionality in PostgreSQL can also be used to speed up full-document searches of XML data, but I do not know the details.

Postgres is free-of-cost and open-source. Very actively developed and supported.

I believe Postgres meets all your criteria, including replication and other clustering technologies, and the bindings. The bundled [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) app is a decent GUI for admin and search, with many other free and commercial tools available as well for Postgres.

Also handles JSON data very well, by the way, better than most of the "NoSQL" systems. Each JSON entry sent to Postgres is parsed into Postgres’ own binary format for internal use. This enables indexing and other powerful features.

Answer (score 0):

May be eXist-db available at http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/homepage/index.html is a good solution for you.